# Repeat minority class to reach a 60%-40% relation

Tags: r, sampling

I am using decision tree to classify my cases. Because my data is unbalanced, I repeated the minority class until I reached a 50:50 equilibrium. I do know, that this is a rather unusual method and I also tried the SMOTE function.

Let's say I had 5% bad cases, then 95% good cases. I repeated my bad data until I had 50% bad and 50% good. The code is below.

```
  #Count frequency of groups
  tab <- table(train$case)

  #Count number of rows to be added
  no_of_rows <- max(tab) - min(tab)

  #count number of rows which are already there in the dataframe for the minimum group
  existing_rows <- which(train$case%in% names(which.min(tab)))

  #Add new rows
  new_df <- rbind(train, train[rep(existing_rows,no_of_rows/length(existing_rows)), ])
  train <- new_df

  #Check the count
  table(train$case)

>   table(train$case)

    bad           good
  15316          15855
```

Now I want to do a 60:40 split. This means 60% bad cases and 40% good cases, but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You should make your example reproducible if possible. How many bad and good cases do you have in your final `train` sample? You can do a random sampling in each population

Comment: Hello ANG,  I just edited my post. However I cannot post a reproducible example, because my dataset is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through this example.

```
train <- data.frame(id = 1:31171, case = c(rep("bad", 15316),
                                           rep("good", 15855))) # a simulation of your train data frame
table(train$case)
#  bad  good 
#15316 15855
prop.table(table(train$case))
#      bad      good 
#0.4913541 0.5086459

# Now you want a new data (say train2) with 60% bad cases and 40% good cases
# First, you have to decide the size of train2 and this task strongly depends on your research question

# But here, let's assume we want to keep all the bad cases
# So all the 15316 bad cases should represent 60% of train2 sample size (instead of 49% in train)
# Therefore, the sample size of train2 should be 25527
15316/0.6
# [1] 25526.67
# This means that you have to add to the 15316 bad cases 10211 good cases
25527-15316
#[1] 10211

# You can now sample those 10211 good cases from the 15855 good cases in train
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
good.cases <- train %>% filter(case == "good") %>% sample_n(10211)

# Now merge the bad cases with the good one you sampled
train2 <- train %>% filter(case == "bad") %>% bind_rows(good.cases)
# Check the distribution of cases
table(train2$case)
#  bad  good 
#15316 10211
prop.table(table(train2$case))
#      bad      good 
#0.5999922 0.4000078
```